# Running a scala script: changing function name and recompiling does not have an effect

Tags: scala, scala-script

After I change the function name from something else to addOptitrans and recompile, I get the following error:

> make final_babylon DICTS=.* bash ../bin/babylon_add_optitrans.sh
>   DICTS=.* /tmp/scalacmd6937716255793087955.scala:1: error: value
>   addOptitrans is not a member of object
>   stardict_sanskrit.batchProcessor
>   stardict_sanskrit.batchProcessor.addOptitrans("DICTS=.*")
>                                    ^ one error found make: *** [final_babylon] Error 1

I have confirmed that the updated class is produced in the expected place in the classpath. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Delete temporary files with `rm -r /tmp/scala*`. Then rerun the command.